what would eat seedlings indoors ?. Snipping the stems and eating the tops
Quick background. We have a sunroom separate from the rest of the house that we covert to a growroom for seedlings in march. In the last week something has been going after our pepper plants. These are plants that have been transplanted from trays to pots and have gotten to the three inch stage with very healthy large leaves. There are two plants in each pot and every morning one plant has been stick one to 1.5 inches up from the soil and the rest of the plant is gone, nothing left but a stem. I'm assuming the top has been eaten. The only plants that have been bothered are the peppers. Would a lone mouse be that orderly and controlled ?. Is there a bug with habits like those that could have come in the soil ?. The height of the cut and the complete eating of the top made me rule out a cutworm. Any thoughts ?.

Do you own a cat? If so, does the cat have access to the sunroom?

Mice is quite likely. One time we had an enormous slug that managed to sneak in. It was probably smaller when it first snuck in, but it was quite sneaky about staying out of sight (hiding between the pots) as it fattened itself... If you have the usual collection of "outdated devices with video cameras" consider setting one up to record overnight. Or use an up-to-date one if that's all you have, or you want to.

There are free motion activated programs out there to set up a laptop to do this.
